# Creating dedicated page for chapters while being present in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I am currently working on the layout of my thesis and not completely certain how to implement this feature. There are two things i wish to achieve:

- A dedicated page for each chapter
- Chapter names being visible in TOC

The TOC structure im looking for is:

```
 Chapter 1: Some chapter name
 
 1 Some title
      1.1 Something elegant ........................................ 5
 
 Chapter 2: Some differnet chapter name
 
 2 Another title
      2.1 Something super elegant .................................. 6
```

Now for each chapter page im looking for something like following:

> Chapter 1
>
> Some chapter name

My starting point is simply a `Chapter x` heading for each chapter created by using following piece of code:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\large\sc\centering}
\chaptertitlefont{\centering}
\subsubsectionfont{\centering}
```

Comment: i'm not familiar with the use of `sectsty`, but it is relatively trivial with the basic toc mechanism to start a new page for each chapter.  just before the `\chapter` command (*in the chapter file, if you use `\include`*), insert a command `\addtocontents{toc}{\newpage}`.

Comment: If i use it along with `sectsty` it still wont appear in the TOC. The TOC looks the same as my example. But a new page appears with `Chapter x` and the chapter name.

Comment: If we assume i use this method. The next problem is that i have another chapter afterward the  `Chapter 1..` which is `1 Some title`, this suddenly becomes 2 instead of 1..

Comment: I just realised what im trying to achieve can simply be done with `\part{..}`. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: adding a `\newpage` command to the `toc` file cannot produce the results you are seeing.  a compilable minimal example. beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` will be needed to figure out what is happening.

Comment: @JavaCake: Can we close this question?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, yes you may!

Comment: @JavaCake: Alternatively you may provide a self-answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was solved by the OP, with the solution left in [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185141/creating-dedicated-page-for-chapters-while-being-present-in-toc#comment428089_185141):

> I just realised what I'm trying to achieve can simply be done with `\part{...}`.

For this question, using `\part` sectioning elements instead of `\chapter` provided the desired output without needing to fiddle with the chapter formatting settings.

Comment: Nice, another one off the list :-)